# using AVPlayer to play a time lapse within a UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, avplayer, avplayerlayer

I am using a custom image/video picker to pick a time lapse, once the picker view has been dismissed I want to play the time lapse within a UIView that I have put on to the view controller in interface builder. This code I have currently is below but the problem is that at the moment when a time lapse is selected it is not played.

**View outlet and var's for video player**

```
@IBOutlet var videoView: UIView!
let ipc = QBImagePickerController()
var playerItem: AVPlayerItem?
var videoPlayer: AVPlayer?
var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer?
```

**did finish picking assets code**

```
func qb_imagePickerController(imagePickerController: QBImagePickerController, didFinishPickingAssets assets: [AnyObject]) {
    for asset in assets as! [PHAsset] {
        PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestAVAssetForVideo(asset, options: nil, resultHandler: {(avAsset: AVAsset?, audioMix: AVAudioMix?, info: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Void in
            self.playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: avAsset!)
            self.videoPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: self.playerItem!)
            self.playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.videoPlayer)
            self.playerLayer!.frame = self.videoView.bounds
        })
    }
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { self.play() })
}
```

**play() function code**

```
func play(){

    videoPlayer!.play()
}
```

**unexpectedly found nil when unwrapping an optional value**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't really know about the library you are using, but it appears to have completion blocks. These are ran in the background thread.

Actually there is a problem : you dismiss your view controller before the variables (player, item etc) were assigned.

Assuming you're new to Swift I'm gonna detail you how your code will behave at runtime :

• Function is called by the delegate when your user picks a photo

• View controller is dismissed, and Player starts playing

• And then your for-loop is ran and the player is assigned an item to play (too late)

What you want to achieve is assigning an item to play and then dismiss the VC. As UI code can only be ran in the foreground (Main Thread), you cannot just move the dismiss function in the completion block, but you will need to use Grand Central Dispatch to run code in the main thread once for-loop finished.

I advise you to download the [Async library](https://github.com/duemunk/Async) in GitHub, which is a wrapper around GCD (once downloaded browse to the Sources folder and drag the Async.swift file in your Xcode project).

Then you will want to edit the "did finish picking assets" function to this in order to play your video :

```
   func qb_imagePickerController(imagePickerController: QBImagePickerController, didFinishPickingAssets assets: [AnyObject]) {

       let photoAssets = assets as! [PHAsset]  

        PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestAVAssetForVideo(photoAssets[0], options: nil, resultHandler: {(avAsset: AVAsset?, audioMix: AVAudioMix?, info: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Void in

            self.playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: avAsset!)
            self.videoPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: self.playerItem!)
            self.playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.videoPlayer)
            self.playerLayer!.frame = self.videoView.bounds

            Async.main { self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { self.play() }) }

        })

}
```

BTW I removed the for-loop coz I figured out you were just willing to pick the first asset in the array. (if wrong tell me!)

Go and try this out and tell me if it works

(More on GCD [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/79149/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-part-1)!)

Comment: I dont have time to test this out right now but this looks perfect. also you are right about the for loop. Thanks alot!!

Comment: I just tried this out but it still does not work, either the app crashes and the console says unexpectedly found nil when un wrapping an optional value or nothing happens at all. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please reproduce the issue and send me the memory stack ? (let the app crash and then in the debugging pane select the method and in the left pane of the console tell me which variable is equal to nil)

Comment: I added an image to the end of the post, I think it is what you want?